# Dynamic input of 2d array with pre-defined 1d arrays

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

Currently, I have working code that reads like this:

```
char input[4][10] = {ARR1, ARR2, ARR3, ARR4};
```

Clearly, I am creating a 2d array with these 1d arrays, which are constants defined elsewhere. However, I need to change this code so that it reads the names of the desired 1d arrays from a file and initializes the 2d array accordingly.

For example, if the file contained:

ARR9
ARR3
ARR5
ARR7

Then the initialization would run like (assume all these arrays are all defined):

```
char input[4][10] = {ARR9, ARR3, ARR5, ARR7};
```

I have no problem reading from the file but am having difficulties with creating the 2d array and with using a value read from the file as a name of an array.

Comment: If you know the size of the 2D array you can malloc a 2D array, and then fill it whith the values of the 1D arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C doesn't have [introspection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection) or [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29), so it's not really possible that way.

You can however have a translation table, that translates from the *strings* `"ARR1"`, `"ARR2"` etc., to the actual arrays, and then you can copy the contents from the actual array to the `input` entry. Or instead of having an array of array like you have now, you can have an array of pointers and just set the pointers to point to the correct array.

Comment: The possible hiccup with this method is that I do not know the names of all arrays that may potentially be passed in via the file. Is it possible to have a translation table that matches a string to the array of the same name (assume a user wrote a valid array name), rather than simply having a mapping between strings and names of arrays that is pre-determined?

Comment: @C.Williamson There is no way of getting identifier names during runtime, identifiers are only a source concept and have no corresponding runtime concept.

Comment: @C.Williamson There is another solution, and that is that the arrays themselves are stored in files that you read during execution of your program. Then you can store them in a file format that have their names and values.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the "constants defined elsewhere" presently look like this

```
const char *ARR1 = "Alpha";
const char *ARR2 = "Bravo";
const char *ARR3 = "Charlie";
```

Solution 1

```
const char *ARR_Value[] = "Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", 0;
const char *ARR_Name[]  = "ARR1", "ARR2", "ARR3", 0;
// Pseudo code
Read file keyword
find matching ARR_Name[]
apply corresponding ARR_Value[] to input[]
```

A more elegant solution

```
typedef struct {
  const char *Name;
  const char *Value;
  } ARR_t;

const ARR_t ARR[] = {
  { "ARR1", "Alpha"},
  { "ARR2", "Bravo"},
  { "ARR3", "Charlie"},
  { 0, 0}
};

// Pseudo code
Read file keyword
find matching ARR[] by doing strcmp(keyword, ARR[i].Name)
apply corresponding ARR[i].Value to input[]
```

---

Not clear if OP needs to initialize and then change input[] contents or not as the post is `char input[4][10]` and not `const char input[4][10]`.

Comment: I see I'm late to the party.